# How to trigger onchange input of type file with view model in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using input of type file to open file and trigger a function on change like this.

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="fileUpload"
              onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileOpened(this)" />
```

my function is like this right now.

```
$scope.fileOpened = function(data) {
  // ...
}
```

it is working fine, but I want to do it in different way. In my controller, I have create a view Modal like

```
var vm = this;
```

and initializing all variables and function with that view model like

```
vm.fileOpened = fileOpened;
function fileOpened() {

}
```

**Now how to trigger it with onchange event, I have tried it like this, but give an error.**

```
onchange="angular.element(this).vm.fileOpened(this)"
```

Comment: just should be  `vm.fileOpened(this)`. Is there only that controller injected in your view?

Comment: may be angular.element(this).scope().vm.fileOpened(this)  shoul do the job?

Comment: happyZZR1400  it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
angular.element(this).scope().vm.fileOpened(this);
```

and

```
vm.fileOpened = function(data) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: with view model, we don't write $scope.fileOpened() {}